# How to setup SSO from web application to sharepoint server?

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on

I have a web application that users authenticate against using their active directory credentials. Within that application are links to the organizations sharepoint server.

Is it possible to configure a single sign on so that when users follow these links to the sharepoint server they are not prompted for credentials again?

Comment: Are you using IE? If so, try adding the SharePoint sites as trusted Intranet sites and configure IE to login automatically to Intranet sites. Depending on your environment you might also have to do some Kerberos/AD/SPN configuration.

Comment: No - it will be a mix of the different browsers.